# How to create and fill 2d list in python. Basically trying to create a list of rgb values

Tags: python, list, rgb, color-coding

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to enter in the red, green, blue of there color and how many tints they want and saving that into a 2d list.  Right now I am just trying to put their rgb value in the list the same number of times they enter for the tint.

So for example they enter
    r = 255
    g = 0
    b = 0
    numTint = 5

I want to fill the list so it is like this  for now:
    tintList = [(255,0,0), (255,0,0), (255,0,0), (255,0,0), (255,0,0)]

The problem is I'm am new to programming an python so I'm am not quite sure how to do this.  I believe you have to use nested loops, but I am not sure how. I would really appreciate any help I can get.

```
def createColorList(r,g,b, numTint):
    tintList = []
    #fill tintList

    return tintList
```

Comment: `tintList = [(r,g,b)]*numTint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def createColorList(r,g,b, numTint):
    tintList = []
    for x in range(0, numTint):
        tintList.append((r,g,b))
    return tintList
```

But I think Use a class to represent RGB value, maybe a better practice.

```
class Color(object):
    def __init__(self, red, green, blue, tint):
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        self.tint = tint

    def somemethod(self):
        pass #you can add some method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension and range:

```
return [(r,g,b) for _ in range(numTint)]


In [25]: createColorList(255,0,0,5)
Out[25]: [(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)]
```